# Find equals in array and add additional information

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to implement a logic where an array contains a number of items (products) which differ by name. Nevertheless, it could be, that the products have the same name, so I would need to add an additional property (size). I guess this is a simple task but I am getting duplicates in my current approach:

```
for (int k = 0; k < items.length(); k++) {
 for (int l = k + 1; l < items.length(); l++) {
  if(items.getString(k).equals(items.getString(l))) {
    buttons.add(new Button(items.getString(k) + " Größe "
                            + items.getJSONObject(k).getString("size");

    buttons.add(new Button(items.getString(l) + " Größe "
                            + items.getJSONObject(l).getString("size");
  }
 }
 buttons.add(new Button(items.getString(k);
}
```

I have adapted the items a little bit to make it easier to read. The Problem I am facing now is that the two added elements with the size attached are now also attached again without the size. So how am I skipping those two elements once I have added them?

Comment: try removing `buttons.add(new Button(items.getString(k) + " Größe "
                            + items.getJSONObject(k).getString("size");`

Comment: But I need to attach the size information to both of the duplicates.

Comment: Could you provide an example of content for `items` , the expected output and the actual output ?

Comment: If `items` is an array, where is the function `items.getString(k)` coming from ?

Comment: It's a JSONArray

Answer (score 0):

Change your approach.

- First group them by name (`Map<String, List<Item>>` for example)
- Then, for each entry in the map, determine if the List has size >1. If so, add the extra information to each item of that list.
- Then, iterate all entries and all lists, and put them back in an big list.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `name` of the product as an identifier is a bad way to go. Also, say you do add the size of the product when 2 products have the same name. Then what are you going to do when the products have the same size and name? Each product needs to have an id.

But, to answer your question, your problem is you are using 2 for loops when you only need one. Just use an if statement to check if both products have the same name inside of one for loop.

```
for (int k = 0; k < items.length(); k++) {
 if(k == items.length() - 1{
    //Last Entry in for loop, don't add anything here or you'll get a null pointer exception
  }
 else{
    if(items[k].productName.equals(items[k+1].productName){
      //2 Products have same name! Do your stuff.
    }
  }

}
```

You never specified what `item` is so change `items[].productName` respectfully to adapt to your code.

Comment: Thanks for the above code. So if the duplicates are found, I am adding them with the size attached...understood. But when in this loop am I adding the non-duplicates? If I am adding an else branch after the duplicate's if, then the last entry of the array is not added, but instead one of the duplicates above.

Answer (score 0):

Mark!
The duplicate must be occured because of buttons.add(new Button(items.getString(k); in the outer loop.
At least if you'll put that line to else-clause it wouldn't appear.

Actually here, if you don't mind about the memory, I'd recommend to use a HashMap() to store pairs of items.getString(k) to List of items.getJSONObject(k).getString("size").

Then you go once thru the collection to to create this hashmap:

```
for(int k = 0;....){
   String key = items.getString(k);
   if(map.contains(key){
      map.get(key).add(items.getJSONObject(k));
   else {
     List<?> list = new ArrayList()
     list.add(items.getJSONObject(k));
     map.put(key, list);
   }
}

map.entrySet().stream().map(stringListEntry -> {
         if (stringListEntry.getValue().size() == 1) {
              return new Button(stringListEntry.getKey());
         } else {
             return stringListEntry.getValue().stream().map(size ->
                       new Button(stringListEntry.getKey() + " Größe " + size));
         }
     }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```